# How to link to an Email account in Dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to link to my email account and i have tried this line
here below but it only works with web pages

```
html.A([html.H6('Feedback')], href=['mailto:example@gmail.com'] , target='_blank')
```

what is wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
html.A([html.H6('Feedback')], title ='email_me', href='mailto:example@gmail.com')
```